# Creating output dir structure with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have a java project XXX

- src/main/java
- src/main/config
- src/main/scripts

I want output structure like

C:/target/XXX.jar
C:/target/scripts

I tried to use resource plugin but it is packing everything inside jar.

```
<build>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/config</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/scripts</directory>
            <targetPath>/scripts</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) is great for this sort of thing. You can create a descriptor something like this (in `src/main/assemble/scripts.xml`):

```
<assembly>
  <id>scripts</id>
  <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <outputDirectory>/scripts</outputDirectory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.*</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Wire this into your build like so:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/main/assemble/scripts.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-scripts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
```

This will bind the execution of the assembly to the package phase of the build.

This method will give you the flexibility to change how you package up the scripts in the future, or copy more resources in the build.